# How to store the resulting array returned by the map function in JS (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

How do i do it ?

> Here is a sample code

i am trying to store the result in an array already initialized to sent to another file ? what to do ?

```
Promise.all(

    trendingMovies.results

      .slice(0, 5) // use slice instead of a loop

      .map((

        trendingMovie // map movie to [language,movie]

      ) =>

        getLanguageNamefromCode(

          // get async language

          trendingMovie.original_language

          // resolve to [language,movie]

        ).then((language) => [language, trendingMovie])

      ) // sorry, forgot to return here

  )

    .then((

      results // results is [[language,movie],[language,movie]]

    ) =>

      results.map(([language, trendingMovie]) => {

        const hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(

          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === trendingMovie.id.toString()

          // snippet does not have conditional chaining

        );

        return new Movie( // create new Movie

          trendingMovie.id.toString(),

          language,

          hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""

        );

      })

    )

    .then((movies) => {

      // loadedTrendingMovies.push(movies);

      loadedTrendingMovies = [...loadedTrendingMovies, ...movies];

      console.log("loadedTrendingMovies", loadedTrendingMovies);

    })

    .catch((err) => console.log(err)
```

}

> What should be the approach ?
>   If i want to study this topic in a greater detail what should i refer to ?
>
> ........... stack overflow wont lemme submit geez

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "store the result in an array already initialized to sent to another file?" Maybe if you posted the code for this other file it'll be clearer to us.

Comment: this is from the and action creator and it dispatches the  array recieved from the map functions to go to the reducer to store in the redux store @Jacob

Comment: So that means you're already storing it in the redux store? Not sure what you're asking, then.

Comment: you see the last then block i need to get the result from there to be stored in a variable which is otherwise undefined so how do i go about it ? similar to how i store loadedTrendingMovies in the said last then block or any other way . my way it does console log correctly but when i useSelector into the store to access it it is empty !!

Comment: Wouldn't you just dispatch `loadedTrendingMovies`? I think we need to see more of your action creator to put this in context.

Comment: https://github.com/Abhishek12345679/moviesTrackerApp

Comment: i linked my repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action creator you're doing this:

```
let loadedTrendingMovies = [];

// ...

Promise.all(...)
  .then(...)
  .then(...)
  .then(movies => {
    loadedTrendingMovies = [...loadedTrendingMovies, ...movies];
  });

// ...

dispatch({
  type: LOAD_ALL,
  movies: loadedStories,
  new_releases: loadedTrendingMovies,
  new_tv_shows: loadedNewTVShows,
  anime: loadedAnime,
});
```

The problem with this is you're not *awaiting* your Promise, so `dispatch` is going to run before your Promise completes.

Your action creator is already an async function, so rather than trying to *assign to* `loadedTrendingMovies`, you should have your Promise *create* that array and then await that as the result of the Promise:

```
const loadedTrendingMovies = await Promise.all(...)
  .then(...)
  .then(results => results.map(...))

dispatch({
  type: LOAD_ALL,
  movies: loadedStories,
  new_releases: loadedTrendingMovies,
  new_tv_shows: loadedNewTVShows,
  anime: loadedAnime,
});
```

Comment: thank you for your effort i'll try tomorrow and give the feedback it's midnight past here